# Cuando redirijo a una nueva pagina se oculta mi "Tabs" en IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, tablas, ionic-framework, vistas

Tengo la siguiente aplicación de ionic:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es el siguiente, cuando hago click en "mi negocio" cargo una nueva pagina de la siguiente forma:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="token != null" (click)="menu.close()" routerLink="/minegocio"> 
     <ion-icon slot="start" name="briefcase-outline"></ion-icon>
     <ion-label> Mi negocio</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

al ejecutarse routerLink="/minegocio" me lleva correctamente a la pagina de "mi negocio" el problema es que se oculta el tabs de abajo y no se como hacer para mostrarlo de nuevo o fijarlo para que no se oculte nunca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A tener en cuenta: la app de ionic esta generada con la plantilla tabs y esta basada en angular.
Espero que me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias por su tiempo y atención. Si necesitan más informacioón codigo o imagenes para ayudarme haganmelo saber.

Answer (score 0):

Para entendernos:
TabBarPage: Dónde tienes la etiqueta ion-tabs

El funcionamiento de Ionic es el esperado ya que el tab-bar sólo se mantiene cuando lo que cargas es un componente hijo de la página TabBarPage (que es como se carga las tab-pages). Por lo que lo que tendrías que hacer es simplemente añadir las páginas en las que quieras tener las tabs al atributo children TabBarPage en el tabpage-routing.module.ts.

Ahora mismo la variable Routes en el archivo TabPage-routing.module.ts deberías tener algo muy parecido (con otros nombres)

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: HomePage,
children: [
  {
    path: 'trendy',
    loadChildren: () => import('./trendy/trendy/trendy.module').then(m => m.TrendyPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    loadChildren: () => import('./new/new/new.module').then(m => m.NewPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfilePageModule)
  }
]
}
];
```

A este código tendrás que añadir un objeto al atributo children por cada página que quieras que tenga la tab-bar con el siguiente formato:

```
  {
    path: <Lo que añades a la url>,
    loadChildren: () => import(<url a la carpeta de la pagina>).then(m => m.<NombreDelModulo>)
  }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
  {
    path: 'tabpage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./../../tabpage/tabpage.module').then(m => m.TabpagePageModule)
  }
```

Comment: Vale, he entendido la respuesta me podrias poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo?